# Postgresql create database from backup programmaticly

Tags: postgresql, backup

I got a big problems here. Let's say I got the table `A` (with columns like `id`, `name` etc) in the main database. So when I making `INSERT` into `A`  I need to create new database lets say `B_id`. I got `.backup` file with database sturcture which suppose to use `B_id` databases.

I guess I need to write trigger which activates script.

But how I suppose to wrtie the script which creates database(with name depends on `id` number) and applies `.backup` file to it? Is it even okay to do like that?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Do you actually mean "database" when you say "database" for "`B_id`" ?

Comment: @CraigRinger yeah I mean new database with tables and stored procedures, triggers etc inside

Comment: So you want to run `CREATE DATABASE` and/or `pg_restore` or load an SQL script, using a trigger, when you do an `insert` into table on a different DB? Why on earth do you want to do that?

Comment: @CraigRinger because I got such task on job ._.

Comment: Then I'm glad I don't have that task. Sounds like a terrible idea, strongly suggest re-thinking the whole thing. Start with "what am I actually trying to achieve by doing this" and go from there.

Comment: @CraigRinger well, I am pretty new to all this but isn't tasks to dynamic database creation are regular?

Comment: @CraigRinger I just don't understand why you been so surprised? and actually it's scary me a little. I guess i'll be fired if i can't make it hah, but whatever I'm just a trainee

Comment: It's not your fault your employer has weird ideas about how to do things. Doing what you want is possible - you can use `dblink` from a trigger, for example. It's just weird, awkward, and clumsy.

Comment: Also, no, dynamic database creation isn't really all that regular. It often suggests a design where someone's "cloning" a whole database for each customer or something. This quickly becomes a maintenance nightmare, and is rarely the best way to do it.

Comment: @CraigRinger oh, could you reccomend the bes way? I guess it's just suppose to be tables with data and with `_id` column of course. But actually I think when I will ask about why we doing this and try to say what I think they will be like "Oh look! We've got a mr smarty pants here" :\

Comment: Not without knowing a lot more about what the actual _goal_ of doing this is, the *why* behind the *how* question you're asking. And realistically, if you're in that kind of company, your only option is to nod, smile, and do what they ask even if it's completely stupid.

Comment: @CraigRinger oh. but however, problem kinda solved - I used Npgsql to create clean DB and then use pg_restore with commands to apply `.backup` to it, used .net for that :\ Seems like it's not ok too but it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a database inside a transaction is not possible, so that precludes doing it directly in a trigger, and more generally in any **function** called by the SQL engine.

The usual method to issue script-like operations from a trigger is to have such script running as a [daemon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29) and listening to events through the SQL [`LISTEN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-listen.html) command, the events being signalled from the trigger with a [`NOTIFY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-notify.html) command, possibly including a payload with parameters. If the transaction is rolled back, its notifications are not sent.

From a design point of view, this is a misuse of triggers. A trigger that "does something" is a side effect by nature and side effects are more a problem than a solution in programming. Creating and populating a new database is a **massive side-effect**.

Unfortunately some think that triggers being cool, they should use and abuse them no matter what problem they're trying to solve.